# Need to break out of iframe after content in iframe is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Ok, I am using an iframe on a page.  The content within the iframe I have no control over and is being utilized with an Adobe Flash program.

But once the form is sumitted within the iframe (again which I have no control over), it loads up a PAGE, I DO HAVE CONTROL Over, but has that page within the IFRAME instead of it breaking out of the iframe on that page.  How do I break out of the iframe on that page only??

I'm assuming that some Javascript is needed, but this code is no good:

```
if (top.location != self.location) {
top.location = self.location;
}
```

Using this code loads up the main index page for the site.  I need it to just load the page after the form is submitted and break out of it.  Again, I have access to the page that gets loaded within the iframe after the form gets submitted within the iframe.

Please help me.

Perhaps a tricky way of doing it is involved?  For example while the page is being loaded?  Or somehow check that the iframe has been submitted?  I control both pages on my website (The page that holds the iframe originally and the page that the iframe gets submitted to), just not the iframes content.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you putting the code in the outer page or in the iframe's page? Also, could you be running into a security issue caused by the outer and inner pages having different domains?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you want this

```
if(this != top){
  top.location.href = this.location.href;
}
```

To break out

It might need the document reference too... I'm not at a computer to check.

```
if(this != top){
  top.document.location.href = this.document.location.href;
}
```

Comment: Where do I put that code?  In the head?  How does it know what `this` is?  Or what `top` is within the Javascript?  Will it know it automatically, or does it have to be defined?

Comment: this does NOT work, it is still taking me to the sites index instead of the URL that the iframe goes to.

Comment: what is the URL of the page? and is there only the one frame?  I ask because I've used this code dozens of times and I know it works.  Yes you can put it in the head or in the body... top is a global reference to the topmost window, and this is automatically refering to "this" window.  PS I may have goofed slightly, it may need the 'document' in the full name.

Comment: argg, this is still taking me to the sites index instead of that page.  Perhaps you would be willing to take a look for me?  Let me know and I'll give you some links.  I have tested the output of this and top, and the hrefs are both correct, but it redirects me to the homepage of my site instead... arggg.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, thanks, I had code further down that was preventing this from happening.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: I've implemented this and the URL changes in the browser, unfortunately, the page doesn't load, its only a URL change. How do I force the browser to load it?

Comment: @clifford_owino it should work... do you have a public site available I could test this on? (and to verify... do you "own" both the main page and the iframe'd page? and does it behave the same on all browsers?)

Comment: it worked, was using it in a WordPress shortcode and hadn't paid enough attention to the WordPress call-stack. Managed to hook it before headers were sent and all is well

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log('window.top.location', window.top.location);
    console.log('window.location', window.location);

    if (window.location !== window.top.location) {
        window.top.location = window.location;
    }
})();
```

Inspired by https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/break-out-of-iframe/

Answer (score 1):

Chris Coyier at [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/break-out-of-iframe/) has a nice succinct explanation of how to do this.

One way is a little clearer to the observer (as much as production Javascript code can ever said to be "clear"):

```
(function(window) {
  if (window.location !== window.top.location) {
    window.top.location = window.location;
  }
})(this);
```

The other is much shorter, but also trickier and less obvious:

```
this.top.location !== this.location && (this.top.location = this.location);
```

Again, credit where credit is due: I didn't write these snippets, I'm just passing them along because they answer the question.