# Break out of iFrame upon action within

Tags: wordpress, iframe, breakout

I'm displaying a form within an iFrame.

The form is from another site which I don't control.

Once the form is submitted (via the submit button), I would like the user to be taken to the resulting page but don't want them to have to view that resulting page within the iFrame.

Currently, that 2nd page loads within the iFrame too.

How do I have it break out of the iFrame upon submit?

I'm doing all this on a wordpress page.

JH

Comment: There should be a workaround.
If not, can I resize the iFrame when next page is loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to break out of iframe after content in iframe is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158903/need-to-break-out-of-iframe-after-content-in-iframe-is-submitted)