# How to check if url in browser has changed by iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe (hosted somewhere else) that changes my url in browser upon clicking a button inside the iframe.

In the browser the url will go from https://www.siteurl.com/#/login to https://www.siteurl.com/#/account

I have tried:

```
if (window.location.toString().includes("account")){
alert("url contains account");
}
```

But this only works if you access https://www.siteurl.com/#/account directly.

Then I thought about the .on("load") function

```
$(function(){
$(window).on("load", function(){
 if (window.location.toString().includes("account")){
 alert("url contains account");
 }
});
});
```

But that does not work at all.
Accessing the iframe is a pain as well because of cross-origin. I have no control over the iframe (except CSS), so this might be a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the current URL the iframe is displaying then this should allow you to access it:

```
document.getElementById('ID_of_your_iframe').contentWindow.location.href
```

The current URL of the browser is by principle accessible under

```
window.location.href
```

If these do not work, you might need to break out of the iFrame - see e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158903/need-to-break-out-of-iframe-after-content-in-iframe-is-submitted)

Comment: It is not the iframe SRC that changes. It is the URL in the browser itself. the content of #document inside the iframe does change

Comment: No matter what I do it does not check if the url changes. Tried this as well `if (window.location.href.indexOf("account") != -1)` It will only work if you access https://www.siteurl.com/#/account directly